# What is the proper way to add new fields to an existing SXA component data source?

Tags: sxa

Original questions asked by a member of the community Friederike Heinze on the #sxa Slack channel.

> I would like to add an image field to the **Link** component. The additional rendering of the image field is no problem thanks to the rendering variants. But if I want to add a template field *Image* to the datasource item, I have to clone the whole rendering, because I am not allowed to edit the default SXA templates.

---

What is the proper way to extend existing component data sources without modifying the original template?

Comment: One thing Pointed out by Friederike was that the Insert Options are not updated on the old folder. For this, you may want to make a copy of the Folder Template and adjust the Insert option to include your cloned link. as well as itself so you don't need to "Create from Template".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adam Najmanowicz provided this nice image to aid in explaining.

[image: Thanks Adam]

1. Under your current tenant site, create a new Datasource Configuration.
2. Select rendering for which this new configuration is used.
3. Specify your new datasource item template; this should inherit from the existing SXA data source item template.
4. Specify the folder containing the data sources.
5. Profit!

**Note:** If you choose the existing *Links* folder the Insert Options do not include your new template. You can either update the Insert Options on the folder to include the necessary template(s) or use a different folder for your custom data sources.

[image: Missing custom template]

Comment: If I could wish for something, the Datasource Configuration items would be inherited in a shared site environment :)